# How to open multiple windows at once and avoid browsers automatically blocking it

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open two different windows in one click, but I get a problem, it only opens one window, and the other window is automatically blocked by the browser.
my code is bellow:

```
var btn  = document.querySelector("#openWindow");
btn.onclick = function(){
    window.open("b.html","nameB");
    window.open("c.html","nameC");
};
```

I tried to use the href attribute of the a tag and the action attribute of the form tag.But no use, the browser still blocked it.

is there a elegant solution to resolve it?

Comment: What drives this UX? Perhaps we can offer a better alternative to opening multiple windows/tabs, which isn't generally great UX and certainly not what one expects as a user when you click a single button/link.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah,the user experience is bad.I try to replace the solution again.But I still want to know how to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not really sure but I think the one causing the issue is actually the browser client trying to prevent the opening of too many emergent windows, you could try tweaking your client configuration to see if that's the cause

Comment: @T.J.Crowder why the browser avoid it ,and How to avoid being blocked.

Comment: in chrome just go to this url: chrome://settings/content/popups, I believe there's actually no way of bypassing this security measure

Comment: @Aboca  yeah,change the setting of chrome Can solve this issue ,But not every user will go to set this manually.

Comment: @dawn Seems like the browser will actually prevent the opening of windows out of the onclick event handler scope and will only allow the opening of one per click

Comment: @Aboca  maybe I should change the way I interact. boss asked for one click to open two windows, so I tried it, but the end result was not satisfactory.

Comment: Browsers disallow it because it was common irritating/nefarious behavior.